# Selenium VBA: Get id of element preceding text

Tags: excel, vba, selenium-webdriver

I have a table like below:

```
<table cellspacing="0" class="MainTab">
<tbody>
<tr>
<td onmouseover="dm.v(this);" onmouseout="dm.u(this);" class="MainTdd" id="mn5972_itm1">
Requisitions
<img id="hmimg_mn5972_itm1" src=https://website/application/Common/Menu/Style/ArrowDown.gif width="14" height="10" alt="">
</td>
<td onmouseover="dm.v(this);" onmouseout="dm.u(this);" class="MainTdd" id="mn5972_itm41">
Expenses
<img id="hmimg_mn5972_itm26" src=https://website/application/Common/Menu/Style/ArrowDown.gif width="14" height="10" alt="">
</td>
```

Each  is a button you can click to open a menu.  Using the id, I can make the click happen but the itm part of the id changes based on user access, so it's not a reliable way to click the button.

I have tried using this code:

```
    Set Exp_Button = driver.FindElementsByXPath("//*[contains(text(),'Expenses')]")
    driver.Exp_Button.Click
```

and

```
    Set Exp_Button = driver.FindElementsByXPath("//*[text()='Expenses']")
```

But since the element is empty, click gives an error saying -  `Object doesn't support this property or method.`

Expecting (and failing) to trigger the button for Expenses.

Thanks!

Comment: Since you are trying `"//*[text()='Expenses']"` im guessing you also tried `"//td[text()='Expenses']"` . Why dont you just get all TD Elements and loop them, and when `elem.text = 'Expenses'` then fire the click.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code below works for me using [your fragment of html](https://davetallett26.github.io/table2.html).

The method is `FindElementByXPath`. The method `FindElementsByXPath` returns multiple elements.

```
Option Explicit
Sub sbExpenses()
    Dim driver As ChromeDriver
    Set driver = New ChromeDriver
    Dim sURL As String
    Dim we As WebElement
    sURL = "https://davetallett26.github.io/table2.html"
    driver.Start ("edge")
    driver.get (sURL)
    sbDelay (100000)
    Set we = driver.FindElementByXPath("/html")
    MsgBox we.FindElementByXPath("/html/body/table/tbody/tr/td[contains(text(),'Expenses')]").Attribute("id")
    sbDelay (100000)
    driver.Quit
End Sub
Sub sbDelay(delay As Long): Dim i As Long: For i = 1 To delay:  DoEvents: Next i: End Sub
```